# How do I include an image in an Android interface?

Tags: android, image

I am creating my first Android interface and I want to include a logo on. The logo is called logo.jpg. How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by including a logo on?  On a splash-screen?  On the titlebar? On a button?  Where??

Comment: I am using Droiddraw, So I am creating a screen. I want to have the logo at the top of each screen I make.

Comment: You should have go through Android SDK atleast for once.

Answer (score 5):

Put logo.jpg into the res/drawable directory. Or if you have different size logos, put them in res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-hdpi, etc. See [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) for detailed information.

To display the image, use [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html). The XML refers to the image like this:

```
android:src="@drawable/logo"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add your logo( name logo.png for example) to the folder `drawable` , and then , add an imageView on your layout xml like this :

```
<ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/logo" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" <!-- this is the drawable source of your imageView -->
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Then place an image view where you would like the logo to be and set the image resource to `R.drawable.logo` or what ever the resource name is.